# Is 18:82 a valid ratio for aqua regia?

Tags: nomenclature, concentration, etymology

[Here](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/nitrohydrochloric+acid) it writes that nitrohydrochloric acid (possibly Aqua Regia) is of the ratio of $18:82$, which is $1:4.56$ in a simpler form. On Wikipedia and every other source i found the ratio $1:3$. So what's the truth behind this?

Also is Aqua Regis a valid way to call the mixture? On [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aqua_regis#English) it says that this is a synomym of Aqua Regia but why would it have such a different ratio then?

Comment: Having made aqua regia fairly regularly during my (short) time in the lab - I never measured it out precisely, and I don't think the exact ratio matters too much... You get a slightly different colour (more nitric acid = more brown), and the exact composition won't be the same, but it'll probably still dissolve what you throw in it. BTW, 18:82 in what units -- volume, mass, etc.? 1:3 refers to the stoichiometry.

Comment: *"Aqua regia"* is "royal water", or more literally "water of kings". *"Aqua regis"* is "water of the king". I would suspect the latter has occurred because people didn't know Latin, or translated the term from their own language back into Latin. (For example, in German it's "Königswasser" which means literally "king's water", though it could also be interpreted as "water of the king" or even "king water"; hence also similar terms in languages spoken around the Baltic Sea and in Scandinavia, where German cultural influence was significant for many centuries.)

Comment: @tripleee, Interesting account. You are right. I checked the etymology it was indeed *aqua regis* until 1612s and by 1650s *aqua regia* appeared.

Comment: thank you for the answers! idk what units is the 18:82 as i just found it on the net 

@M. Farooq could you tell me which etymology dictionary you used for checking the word?

Comment: It is called the Unabridged Oxford English Dictionary (www.oed.com). I think it is 22 volumes in print if I remember correctly. Unfortunately, it is not free and you have to pay for subscription or a library has a license. The ordinary OED does not have dates with usage examples.

Comment: I think without units it is hard to come up with a sensible answer to the ratio question, unless someone can figure out / reverse engineer the significance of the "magic" numbers 18:82 and how it relates to the usual ratio 1:3.

Comment: Aqua regia does not have that rigid fixed composition as the OP is suggesting. There is **no** magic in his 18:82 numbers.

Comment: @orthocresol There is a footnote in the wikipedia article of aqua regia which says "The relative concentrations of the two acids in water differ; values could be 65% w/v for nitric acid and 35% w/v for hydrochloric acid – that is, the actual HNO3:HCl mass ratio is less than 1:2".